# Unbound ComboBox populates another combobox

Tags: vba, combobox

How do I get a combobox to populate depending on what value you chose in another combobox?  The first combobox values come from a table. The second combobox could either be a list or a date.  Working on list part right now. If the value will give a list, the unbound combobox is visible and enabled.  That works - I just can't get the second combobox to populate - should be values from another "code" table.  Tried when exiting the first combobox OR when entering the second combobox.  Neither works (used same code).  Help!

```
Private Sub Combo746_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strsql As String

If (Me!Combo746.Value = "Category") Then
    Me.Combo750.Enabled = True
    Me.Combo750.visible = True
    Me.Text748.Enabled = False
    Me.Text748.visible = False
    Me.Combo750.SetFocus
    strsql = "Select [Category] FROM [dbo_CodesCategory]"
    Me!Combo750.RowSource = strsql
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. First combobox does not populate second combobox, but instead goes to the correct combobox with values.  To explain - Department values are in the Department combobox - combodept.  Category values are in a Category combobox - combocat.  First combobox has values Category and Department.  If the user picks Department, combodept for Department will be visible, combobox for Category- combocat - will be invisible.  Here is the code:

```
If (Me!Combo746.Value = "Category") Then`
    
    Me.ComboCat.Enabled = True
    Me.ComboCat.visible = True
    Me.ComboDept.Enabled = False
    Me.ComboDept.visible = False

    Me.ComboCat.SetFocus

Else
    If (Me!Combo746.Value = "Department") Then
    
        Me.ComboDept.Enabled = True
        Me.ComboDept.visible = True
        Me.ComboCat.Enabled = False
        Me.ComboCat.visible = False
        
        Me.ComboDept.SetFocus
    
    End If
End If
```